# Comparing values in same columns, different rows - MySQL

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have this Student TABLE:

```
ID           Name               Age
1            Billy              11
2            Ben                15
3            Ivy                21
4            Alice              30
5            Don                69
```

How do I SELECT the person that has the Greatest Age? How do I get the person with the least Age? Is this Possible? Is this also possible if I have like hundreds of Rows?

The output must be like this:

```
ID          Name             Age
5           Don              69
```

I really need your help. Any Ideas?

Comment: What query did you attempt?  You should research first then try then ask, otherwise you do not learn anything except copy paste.

Comment: I researched before asking but I can't find what I want. That's why I decided to ask

Comment: You didn't, limit and order are very basic parameters for slq's

Comment: Group by is even more basic than limit as it has been a part of sql since inception. Afraid your research technique needs more work than your sql.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the student with the greatest age is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM Student
WHERE Age = (SELECT MAX(Age) FROM Student)
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Another option is to use `ORDER BY` along with `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Student
ORDER BY Age DESC
LIMIT 1
```

**Update:**

As the @strawberry pointed out, these two queries are not strictly identical.  The first query will return *all* students who have the max age, should there be a tie for oldest student.  However, the second query will return only a single record, even in the event of a tie.

Comment: But note that these two queries are not equivalent

Comment: Thank You for your idea. I think the sub query is the best suited for my system. But when I try the query it returns 0 results.

Comment: @RyuggaHideki Then there is a problem with your query or data.  Have a look at this demo to see the query in action: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dbfd68/1).

Comment: Thank you :) I Fixed My Problem. You Really Saved Me :)